# mac terminal root indicator

Tags: macos, command-line, terminal

How do I make command prompt to end with # if I do sudo -s in mac terminal?

Right now I have $.

Comment: Uhh, I have a default installation, and it gives me `#`. How have you customized your environment?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're using bash, you

```
export PS1='\$ '
```

the `\$` becomes the `#` or `$` prompt depending on if your id==0.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `export SUDO_PS1="prompt"`

Instead of `prompt`, you write whatever your prompt should look like. For example:

```
export SUDO_PS1="\\$"
```

This will show only `#` when you're root. You can use the same line/placeholder for `PS1`, it'll show up as `$` when you're a regular user.

To get the same prompt as a normal user when you're root, i.e. the following:

```
host:/Users/username root#
```

you need to enter this:

```
export SUDO_PS1="\[\h:\w\] \u\\$ "
```

---

Add the `export` line to your `~/.bash_profile` if you want to keep it.